# Assigning variables to pointers

Tags: c

When compiling the below, the program seem to crash. However, there is no error in the compiling process.

```
...
int *x;     
*x = 3;
printf("%d", *x);
...
```

From what I know, this program declares the pointer `*x` to an integer value, and subsequently assigns the value of 3 to the deferenced pointer `*x`.

So why does the program crashes? If I do this instead, the program can work normally.

```
...
int *x, y; 
y = 3;
x = &y;    
printf("%d", *x);
...
```

So, what seems to be the problem with the skipping of the y variable, and instead, assigning the pointer *x directly to an integer value?

Comment: "this program initializes the pointer `*x` " - no. `*x` is not a pointer. `x` is a pointer, `*x` is the result of dereferencing that pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From what I know, this program initializes the pointer *x to an
>   integer value, and subsequently assigns the value of 3 to the
>   deferenced pointer *x.

That is incorrect.  `int *x;` declares an int pointer, but *it does not initialize it to anything*.  What `x` points to at this time is unknown, and depends on the current state of memory.  Before you can dereference a pointer, you need to set it to point to something (eg, `x = &y;`).

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean that I have assigned the integer 3 to an unallocated memory address?

Comment: Well, it means you've tried to assign it to an unallocated address.  You should get a segmentation fault before that happens.

Comment: I found that by adding two lines of code `int z; x = &z`, the program would work, even though z is not used at all. Is this what is meant by allocating a memory address to the pointer *x (or initializing the pointer)?

Comment: @tys: yes, z is used.  It is an integer and therefore has a storage location ... and you take the address of this storage location and place it in x.  `int *x` just produce a storage location for the pointer (but not for what it is pointing to ... that you have to do yourself ... e.g. as you are here with `x= &z`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the knowledge, I am beginning to understand pointers and addresses slightly better now (it was a bit confusing for me as I just started). Really appreciate all these help.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that in the first case pointer 'x' doesn't point to a valid memory location. And you're trying to change the value of un-allocated memory which your program doesn't own.
Pointers must always be initialized properly before they are used.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example x is uninitialized and therefore doesn't point to valid memory.

You could change your code to

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));     
*x = 3;
printf("%d", *x);
```

and it would work.

In your second example

```
int *x, y;
```

You are declaring x as a pointer and y as a normal int variable, not another pointer. If you wanted 2 pointers the syntax would be.

```
int *x, *y;
```

This can be confusing and is part of the reason some C programmers never declare multiple variables on one line.

```
x = &y;
```

Here you are assigning the address of y to x and therefore causing x to point to valid memory and a subsequent assignment through dereferencing the pointer will work.

You would find that if you printed the value of y then it would also be 3 as you changed it through x.